# Where can I find reviews of a set once it's established?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The only set reviews I can find are when the set first comes out. Does anybody know of a reputable site that reviews the cards after a few months when the cards are more established? I am more interested in limited (draft) reviews.

Comment: After a few months it's a bit late as the next set is shortly to be released, no...?

Comment: True, maybe a few weeks is more realistic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Channelfireball.com](http://www.channelfireball.com) LSV makes a scaling from 1-5 after a few weeks the set is released gives his opinion to each card.